# Help with understanding this proposition regarding non-degenerate bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reworking a proof of a proposition so that I can be sure I understand it correctly, but I am getting a little stuck.

Consider the following proposition:

$B$ a reflexive bilinear form on a vector space $V$ and $W$ a non-degenerate subspace. Then $ V = W \oplus W^{\bot}$

Proof

By definition, $W \cap W^{\bot} = \{ 0 \}$. It suffices to show that $\dim(V) = \dim(W) + \dim(W^{\bot})$. Let $\dim(W) = m$ and $\dim(V) = n$. Let $\{ v_1,...,v_m \}$ be the basis of $W$, and extend this to a basis of $V$: $\{ v_1,...,v_m \} \cup \{ v_{m+1},...,v_{n} \}$. Let $ \tilde{v} \in W^{\bot}$ be non-zero and write $\tilde{v} = c_1 v_1+...+c_n v_n$. Since $v \in W^{\bot} \implies B(v_i, \tilde{v}) = 0$ for $1 \le i \le m$. Then for each $i \in [1,..,m]$, $\sum_{j=1}^{n} B(v_i, v_j)c_j = 0$. So $\tilde{v}$ is in the kernel of an $m \times n$ matrix $\hat{B}$ where the top $m$ rows of $\hat{B}$ coincide with the matrix corresponding to $B$.

I am ok with this proof until this point, where the claim is made that:

$\dim(W^{\bot}) \ge n-m$.

However, it's not immediately obvious to me why this is so. I seem to have shown that $\dim(W^{\bot}) \subseteq Ker \hat{B}$.

I know by rank nullity that $\dim(V) = \dim(Ker \hat{B}) + \dim(Im \hat{B})$, which would give me $\dim(Ker \hat{B}) = \dim(V) - \dim(Im \hat{B}) = n-m $, but this does not imply  $\dim(W^{\bot}) \ge n-m$?

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please specify, how does the result depends on $B$? May be I am missing something clear, but imho the proposition concerns only the spaces and *not* the $B$.

Comment: The orthogonal of $W$ is w.r.t. the bilinear form I suppose? I also presume that it is supposed non-degenerate?

Comment: When you say that $W$ is non-degenerate, do you mean that the restriction of $B$ to $W$ is non-degenerate?

Comment: Just thinking of $B(v,w)=0$ for all $v \in V$ implies $w=0$ (any $w\in V$).

Comment: In other words the matrix is nonsingular, right? And the orthgonality $\perp$ is rather $\perp_B$. Also the reflexivity can be viewed as the matrix being symmetric,right?

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that the implication
$$\tilde{v} \in W^{\perp_B} \Rightarrow B(v_i,\tilde{v})=0, i=1,\dotsc ,m$$
is actually equivalency? Then it would solve the problem using the [Dimension of Sum and Intersection of Vector Spaces](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Sum_and_Intersection_of_Vector_Spaces). May be I am missing something, feel free to opose.